# How do I solve an error in showing the result of a decorator?

Tags: python, function, typeerror, python-3.4, python-decorators

I'm learning Python 3 and want to write a simple code to learn about decorators. I tried to run this code:

```
def makebold(fn):
    def wrapped():
            return '<b>' + str(fn) + '</b>'
    return wrapped()

def makeitalic(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return '<i>' + str(fn) + '</i>'
    return wrapped()

@makebold
@makeitalic
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

print(hello())
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Msn Folder\92\Python\Projects\PythonSamplesByMsn\05 Functions\D03_Decorator01.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(hello())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What have I done wrong? How can I correct this?

Comment: Decorators should return *callables*, not *the result of calling them*; `return wrapped` (note no parentheses). At least then it will run, and your next error should be pretty clear from the output...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must remove `()` at end of `return wrapped()` and change `str(fn)` to `str(fn())` because `fn` function object must called.

use this

```
def makebold(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return '<b>' + str(fn()) + '</b>'
    return wrapped

def makeitalic(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return '<i>' + str(fn()) + '</i>'
    return wrapped


@makeitalic
@makebold
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

print(hello())


<i><b>Hello World</b></i>
```

Comment: Do you understand *why* those changes were necessary?

Answer (score 3):

To start with, note that

```
@bar
def foo():
    ...
```

is just shorthand for:

```
foo = bar(foo)
```

i.e. you *replace* the function with the result of calling `bar` with the function itself. After this, therefore, `foo('baz')` is really `bar(foo)('baz')`, i.e. attempting to call *whatever is returned by `bar`*.

It is for this reason that the return value from a function used as a decorator *must itself be callable*. Your "decorators", however, return *strings*, which are **not** callable. If we define:

```
def bar(func):
    return 'bar'
```

then it is clear that `bar(foo)('baz')` becomes `'bar'('baz')`, resulting in the error that you're seeing:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Your decorators return strings because you *call `wrapped`*, and therefore return whatever it returns (a string):

```
return wrapped()
            # ^ note parentheses in your version
```

rather than returning the function itself:

```
return wrapped
            # ^ and their absence when fixed
```

---

The second error you have is that inside the `wrapped` functions, you have:

```
return '<b>' + str(fn) + '</b>'
```

Here you have the **opposite problem** to above - you are making a string of *the function itself*, rather than using the string the function returns.

Remember the decorator is called with the function it's decorating as an argument, i.e. that `fn` inside the decorator refers to *the function being decorated* (e.g. `hello` for `makebold`). What you actually want to wrap the tags around is *what the wrapped function returns* (which is already a string, so you don't need to call `str`:

```
return '<i>' + fn() + '</i>'
               # ^ again, parentheses are important!
```

You could also use proper string formatting, rather than `+` concatenation:

```
return '<i>{}</i>'.format(fn())
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
def makebold(fn):
    def wrapped():
            return '<b>' + str(fn()) + '</b>'
    return wrapped

def makeitalic(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return '<i>' + str(fn()) + '</i>'
    return wrapped

@makebold
@makeitalic
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

print(hello())
```

You should call the wrapped function in the decorator method.

The decorator method must return a function object.

Comment: Note that this only fixes one of the OP's errors, as would be clear if you'd run it...

Comment: I tried this, It works and has no error now, but the result is:**<b><function makeitalic.<locals>.wrapped at 0x002E4AE0></b>**, I guessed that result must be: **<b><i>hello world</i></b>**. How can I achieve that instead of this result?

Comment: @mehdisoltani why don't you spend some time thinking about it? Follow the logic through your code (it may help to know that `@decorator` is just syntactic sugar for `func = decorator(func)`) and read the output carefully.

Comment: @jonrsharpe please try again, it will show `<b><i>Hello World</i></b>`